# Group option in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-point

I get an error in the group option:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 2nd layer.
Caused by error in `check_aesthetics()`:
! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (30)
✖ Fix the following mappings: `group`

```
 test=structure(list(pay = c(1.65041035963578, 1.52885759360691, 1.5477592978624, 
3.28256244574176, 0.576176190105593, 1.08856835010054, 1.565373165872, 
1.16814146076462, 0.93970447828317, 1.00107038709093, 0.357674444271816, 
0.493187176940954, 1.01918300392336, 0.366764473024169, 0.448573127680917, 
1.22364454070333, 1.692103761278, 1.93553638428094, 2.41461105512557, 
2.38040567202902, 2.46777066384127, 3.02871772240225, 2.79396590583994, 
0.332894415273329, 0.0409499863289542, 0.341388702401031, 0.342298090473989, 
0.650624261120054, 1.12077259197701, 1.66183224046159), Vshare = c(0.423076923076923, 
0.166666666666667, 0.358778625954198, 0.529411764705882, 0.705521472392638, 
0, 0.4, 0.165584415584416, 0.452830188679245, 0.371212121212121, 
0.75, 0.555555555555556, 0, 0.5, 0.198174706649283, 0.25, 0.444444444444444, 
0.38655462184874, 0.343434343434343, 0.264285714285714, 0.435897435897436, 
0.606060606060606, 0.272727272727273, 0.245731254639941, 0.666666666666667, 
0.909090909090909, 0.55, 0.733333333333333, 0.322147651006711, 
1)), row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = "data.frame")

plot2 = rdplot(y=test$pay, x = test$Vshare, c=0.5, p=2, ci=95, nbins=10,kernel = "tri", hide=TRUE ) #triangular and epanechnikov seem to work better
data2 = as.data.frame(test$vars_bins)
data2$Union = ifelse(test$rdplot_mean_x>=0.5,1,0)

plotSR = ggplot(data=test, aes(x=Vshare, y=pay, group=Union)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0.5) + 
  geom_smooth(method = "gam",formula= y ~ poly(x, 4),
              se=TRUE)+
  labs(y = "Payment at t+1", x = "Vote Share")+
  geom_point(data=data2, color="black", aes(x=rdplot_mean_x, y=rdplot_mean_y, group=Union))

plotSR + theme(text = element_text(size = 20))
```

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) which includes the code and data to reproduce your issue, e.g. assuming that the data you shared via `dput()` refers to `test` I got an error `object 'Union' not found`.

Comment: `data2` has `Union`, `temp` does not. Shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes. test data is provided with my codes via dput(). Union is an object in the new created data2 in line below plot2.

Comment: To rephrase what Jon said, your `geom_smooth` inherits `data = test` and `aes(x=Vshare, y=pay, group=Union)`. So it will try to draw a smooth for each `Union`, but `Union` doesn't exist in `test`. Also, your `data2` definition doesn't work as `test$vars_bins` doesn't exist, so your code is not reproducible. Start an new R session, run the code above, and you'll see that it doesn't work.